# C++ Multiple inheritence from interfaces and casting

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

If I have a class that inherits from one interface (below) and `wxPane`

```
class iClassA
{
public:
    virtual ~iClassA() {}
    virtual bool FuncA() = 0;
};
```

Concerete:

```
class ConcereteClass : public iClassA, wxPane
{
public:
    bool FuncA();
};
```

Is is acceptable to have a `std::vector` of type `iClassA *` that contains my `ConcereteClass` or will the `vmaps` get confused on casting?

Comment: What are `vmaps` ? What problem are you anticipating ? There's surely no issue in storing derived instance through their base class, that's what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: Attention:  `class ConcreteClass : public iClassA, public wxPane` ! The way you've written means **private inheritance** of  wxPane :  that is only ConcreteClass is aware that it inherits it and the outside worlds can't access any of the  wxPane  members/functions.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable. This is a pretty common pattern too.

```
std::vector<iClass*> v;
v.push_back(new ConcreteClass);
v[0]->FuncA(); // calls ConcreteClass::FuncA();

if (ConcreteClass* cc = dynamic_cast<ConcreteClass*>(v[0])) {
    // succeeds
}

delete v[0];   // correctly calls ConcreteClass::~ConcreteClass()
```

Note that you're inheriting from `wxPane` `private`ly.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I wasn't sure if any data within the concerete class would be lost as it's stored in the map as only part of the inheritence tree

Comment: Also, note that it may be a good idea to use some form of smart pointer in the vector instead, then you are explicit about ownership and resource management.